# Can I create views for all indexing needs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've got 3 systems:

```
Billing System
Tax System
AmericaGreatAgain System
```

...that speak directly with my database.

```
Employee table
columns: pk, ssn, last, first, dob
```

1. The *billing* system depends on an index on **ssn**
2. The *Tax* system depends on the **last/first** index
3. *AmericaGreatAgain* System depends on an index on **dob**.

**In order to accomodate all three systems, would it be a standard solution to create views on the same Employee table, accomodating for the indexing needs of their consumers?**

In the following example, we are creating a view and indexing that view:

```
CREATE VIEW Sales.vSalesSummaryCustomerProduct
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  CUST.CustomerID ,
            SOH.SalesOrderID ,
            SOD.ProductID ,
            SUM(SOD.OrderQty) AS TotalOrderQty ,
            SUM(LineTotal) AS TotalValue ,
            COUNT_BIG(*) AS CountLines
    FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
            INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
                   ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
            INNER JOIN Production.Product PROD
                   ON PROD.ProductID = SOD.ProductID
            INNER JOIN Sales.Customer CUST
                   ON SOH.CustomerID = CUST.CustomerID
            INNER JOIN Person.Person PER
                   ON PER.BusinessEntityID = CUST.PersonID
    GROUP BY CUST.CustomerID ,
            SOH.SalesOrderID ,
            SOD.ProductID; 
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_vSalesSummaryCustomerProduct
  ON Sales.vSalesSummaryCustomerProduct(CustomerID, SalesOrderID, ProductID); 
GO
```

The question is, what an individual index was needed to the same result set:

```
CREATE VIEW Sales.vSalesSummaryCustomerProduct1 ---- new one
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  CUST.CustomerID ,
            SOH.SalesOrderID ,
--etc
index on another column


CREATE VIEW Sales.vSalesSummaryCustomerProduct2 ---- new one
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  CUST.CustomerID ,
            SOH.SalesOrderID ,
--etc
index on another column
```

**What it be a standard practice to proceed with this type of speed optimization strategy by simply creating many views of the same BASE data, creating indexes on what ever is needed?**

Comment: You'll need to provide code and an attempt at solving this.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-indexed-views-the-basics/)

Comment: Do you have a performance issue? How many records in `Employee` ? You would definitely consider creating indexes on the _base table_. Creating indexes on a _view_ is generally unnecessary and has other repercussions

Comment: a view and an indexed view are separate concerns. Do you have an actual measured performance problem?

Comment: @MitchWheat i don't have that, but the reason i ask is because i am planning to do this, and though i wouldnt consider myself a beginner with tsql, i've never heard of a solution where you simply increase speed by adding indexed views

Comment: you increase performance by adding indexes on the underlying table. Views are a functional concern; indexes are a non-functional concern. Stay away from indexed views unless you really know you need them

Comment: well isn't a view just a copy of the underlying table?

Comment: no, it is not a copy; unless it is an indexed view, which persists data on disk. if you have a complicated, aggregated query that needs persisting to disk to reduce I/O, an indexed view may be the right tool

Comment: so basically they are just indexes upon indexes, meaning that you can never have this functionality, where you replicate, in-memory the same table but indexed differently

Comment: Why would you want a 'replica' of the table? Are you concerned about three different apps hitting it? Try 300 users hitting it. All you need to do is add indexes to the base table. Do you actually have a performance issue?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, it's got 2.5 billion rows (suffice it to say that the table is not named employee) :)

Comment: Oh - that's a lot. Why don't you try just indexing the base table first. It's also important to take some kind of measurement before and after so you can understand what difference you made. Indexed views are a whole new ball game and seem unecessary from your description. What indexes currently exist on the table? Does it have a clustered index? If you are having performance issues, choosing the correct clustered index is important. Note that the clustered index _DOES NOT_ need to be the same as the primary key.